# framework code not showing up in git?

Tags: php, git, frameworks, admin-generator

So, I'm working on a PHP project and I'm using this framework: https://github.com/jonseg/crud-admin-generator

But, when I go to commit the files to my git repo, the only files I see are the ones originally created by me. Why aren't I seeing this framework or the changes I've made to this framework? Why can't I commit any of these files? I'm kind of new at git so I'm sorry if this is an easy one...

I have tried searching for all .git files and removing them, running "rm -fr .git" in that directory, making random changes to files, and committing from the command line.

Comment: Did you `clone` from that framework?  Or just set up your own repository bare?  A git `commit` only applies changes to your local repository-- to change the instance at https://github.com/jonseg/crud-admin-generator would require a `git push`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: if you are using composer for dependency management, the files will end up in a folder called `vendor`. Many people consider it best practice to *not* commit files produced by dependency management systems.

Comment: I used composer. Why should they not be committed? I made changes to them so shouldn't the rest of my team see them? How can I override this?

Comment: Also, sorry for the double comment, but I saw all those files in "vendor" and I couldn't get them to commit. I tried removing the .git files in there and it still wasn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `.gitignore` file? It could be that the `.gitignore` file is specifying that Git should ignore the files in the framework.

Comment: Yes, for my own PHPStorm files. None of the files for the framework are in there.

Answer (score 0):

im sorry to ask this obvious question but .. did you pushed after you commit ?

Because the usual flow of using git is :

- Clone from github / init empty forlder for git.
- Add your files with "git add -a" (-a stands for add all files in current folder)
- commit : git commit -m "my commit message"
- push : git push origin master

If you don't Add before you commit, it cannot work.
if you don't push after you commit, it cannot work.

maybe you can have a look at here for getting started using git :
https://git-scm.com/doc

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I don't even get that far. I'm using source tree and it won't even see that any of these files had been modified or needed to be added.

Comment: Maybe because you need to click "Add/remove" to add all files that are not already versionned.
(there will be a popup, just click "yes")

http://gyazo.com/7c906b465f49137044a4b0466f4356cd

Comment: All that that wants to do is add the ignored .git file =(